# passing variable to function with & in the header

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am doing a procedure and it's working but I'm not sure if it'll work in all cases as it's not conventional.

```
void func (int &num){
    num=blah;
}

int main() {
    int num;
    func(num);
}
```

I know the conventional way of doing this is as below but still I have a lot of code in the previous format I prefer not to change as it works just fine. What I don't understand is whether I'm just being lucky.

```
void func (int* num){
    *num=blah;
}

int main() {
    int num;
    func(&num);
}
```

In fact there is a bit more complicated version of it as well:

```
void func(float* &list){
    list=new float[3];
}

int main() {
    float *list;
    func(list);
}
```

which again I understand the conventional way of doing it is as below.

```
void func(float** list){
    *list=new float[3];
}

int main(){
    float *list;
    func(&list);
}
```

Your help is much appreciated as I'm in total confusion.

Comment: You can't use the C++ reference operator (&) with C.

Comment: actually I'm using C++ , I thought pointers are C topic

Comment: may I suggest that you'd read up some things first?

Comment: @Kiarash - C++ has pointers too.  Your question involves C++ and not C, so I retagged it appropriately.

Comment: c'mon I know C++ has pointers too but my assumption was they are not improved in C++. anyway, thanks I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example is correct - you're passing an `int` by reference to `func()`.

Your second example also fine (now that you've edited it).  In this case, you're passing an `int *` by value to `func()`.

Your third and fourth examples are also both correct.  In the third, you're passing a `float *` by reference.  In the second case, you're passing a `float **` by value (which is semantically similar to passing a `float *` by reference, which might be why you're confusing them).

There's nothing "conventional" or "unconventional" about any of your example code.  All of it is 100% correct and will work fine.  Though there are some subtle semantic differences between passing pointers by value and passing by references, these examples are ok.

Comment: the first and second example are supposed to do the same thing. also third and fourth should do the same.

Comment: The signature of `func()` in the second has been changed to `func(int* num);`.

Comment: @Jens, no, I fixed it up for the OP. hmjd - I'll fix up my answer.

Comment: Hm, now the question changed completely, is tagged with another programming language... Indeed quite a confusion.

Comment: @Jens - the OP is a new user and tagged it incorrectly.  I made some edits to clean up the post and hopefully make it more useful to the site.

Comment: @Carl, yes I understand that. Coaching newbies is nice, but I'd expect them at least to read up a minimum about their question, first.

Comment: @Jens - that doesn't mean that cleaning up the question won't help other future new people who might find this question via a web search....

Answer (score 1):

The syntax with `int &` is not C, but C++. It is a so-called reference. If your C (*not* C++) compiler accepts is, then it is a non-standard extension (for a C++ compiler it's part of the language, of course).

The basic mechanics of a reference is that it acts as a name (or another name) for an existing object. For example:

```
int a;
int& b = a;
b = 3; /* equivalent to a = 3 */
```

One way to think about the reference is as an automatically dereferenced pointer (that's also how it is commonly implemented). That is, the above code is equivalent to

```
int a;
int* pb = &a;
*pb = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Form `Func(int &x)` is the c++ form of pass by reference c does not support this.  It is logically equivocation of passing by a pointer.  The comnplier take the address for you implicitly in the call.

In C you would allways declare

```
Func(int *x)
{ ... }
```

And call it

```
Func(&SomeInt);
```

Comment: If the value cann be null then you should declare the int * version if the value cannot be null declare the int & version.

Comment: int * means a Pointer to an int,  int & means a reference to int,  int * * would mean a pointer to a pointer to an int.